# MVC 3 Razor - Create DisplayTemplate for specific Property Name e.g. WebsiteUrl, IsActive

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, razor, display-templates

I have very strict naming conventions for my models and I am wondering if I can leverage this via display templates for common fields like - WebsiteUrl, IsActive, UpdateDate, InsertDate?

Is it possible to create a Display Template based on a property's name?

EDIT:

I am aware that I can achieve this using something like this:

```
@Html.DisplayFor(model => model.Farmer.WebsiteUrl, "WebsiteUrl")
```

I am just wondering if there is a more strongly typed way of doing it.

Comment: Templates are applied by type, not name.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can use the UIHint("") attribute on your models, the name is the name for the file within your shared/EditorTemplates folder.  i do this for things like upload box,  jquery datepicker, WYSIWYG editor etc

Comment: http://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/archive/2009/07/31/asp-net-mvc-v2-preview-1-released.aspx

Comment: Oh nice!! thanks for this :-) not quite what I wanted as it requires still more meta data decorating but it's better than nothing. And I will probably be grateful doing it this way as doing it the way I wanted to will end up with me coming unstuck when I don't want a particular property to be assigned to a common label.